# Change text colour two times with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm messing around `ww3schools` with some examples. I have this code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000).css("color", "green");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">jQuery is fun!!</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

What happens is that when I click the button the text imidiately turns green and the slide animations execute one after the other.

Why doesn't the text first turn red, then the slides execute and then the text turns green ?

What is the logic behind such behaviour? Please enlighten me :)

PS: I know I can achive the efect using a callback. The question is why doesn't this chaining work ?

Comment: Look into the complete callbacks of the jQuery animations.

Comment: The logic is that only items that are added to a queue will wait for the previous asynchronous calls to finish. This primarily includes animations and things like `.delay()`. If *every* synchronous method was queued, it would have an impact on performance.

Comment: @squint Thank you. So i guess changing the color is not considered an animation :)

Comment: Correct. An animation is a series of small changes over a duration of time. They are done asynchronously otherwise  the browser would freeze during then and you wouldn't actually see the animation.

Comment: Thank you all for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call three jQuery functions, `.css()`, `.slideUp()`, and `.slideDown()`. The calls to `.css()` happen immediately and in sequence, which is why you see the green color but not the red (if you could slow time down, you'd see the red flash for an instant).

The calls to `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` however are queued so that that will complete one after the other. As noted on [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/):

> Queues are the foundation for all animations in jQuery, they allow a
>   series functions to be executed asynchronously on an element. Methods
>   such as `.slideUp()`, `.slideDown()`, `.fadeIn()`, and `.fadeOut()` all use
>   `.animate()`, which leverages queues to build up the series of steps
>   that will transition one or more CSS values throughout the duration of
>   the animation.

This is why the the events happen in the order you see. If you want the final `.css()` call to occur after the `.slideDown()` you need to place it within the `.slideDown()`'s callback like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000, function() {
      $(this).css("color", "green")
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">jQuery is fun!!</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on what @alex said, you can create a "callback function" for `slideDown`, that will get called when the animation is complete. Here you can change the color to green, like this

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000, function() {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">jQuery is fun!!</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the button it started to scroll up with red color, and when started to scroll down it's color become green.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("p").css("color", "red").slideUp(1000 ,function() {
            $("p").css("color", "green").slideDown(1000)});
        })
});
```